# Adding Git repo and branch to Tmux status line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, git, tmux

I have found [a Tmux configuration file](https://gist.github.com/snuggs/800936) that shows how to add the Git branch to the Tmux status line, however It just shows `[[  branch ]]` no matter if I am in a Git repo or not. I am not sure if this requires `git-completion`, but if so I'm not even sure if it is installed as it is a 'virtual' package in Ubuntu (the leading 'v' means 'virtual'):

```
$ aptitude search git-completion
v   git-completion

$ sudo apt-get install git-completion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-completion'
git is already the newest version.
```

How might I add the branch and also the git repo name for the CWD to the Tmux status line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I developed a Bash script for doing that: [tmux-git](https://github.com/drmad/tmux-git).

tmux-git shows the Git branch of the current working directory, and also checks for uncommited and stashed changes.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, just provides a workaround for `bash` users.

Answer (score 14):

This is a lot easier in newer versions of tmux:

```
set -g status-right '#(cd #{pane_current_path}; git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

Comment: This works, but it does not update when I change directory or git branch. It only updates when I use the tmux prefix to update tmux's state.

Answer (score 5):

I developer a platform and shell-independent solution to show Git working tree information into Git status bar: [gitmux](https://github.com/arl/gitmux).
Here's the screencast on the project page`README`:

[image: gitmux screencast]

As well as showing the branch and remote, it shows additional information about the status of the Git working tree :

- number of commits **ahead** / **behind** upstream branch, **branch divergence**
- number of **changed** files, **staged**, **modified**, **conflicts** and *stashes** elements
- **colors**

## How it works

By adding `set -g status-right '#(gitmux #{pane_current_path})'` to your `.tmux.conf`, `gitmux` gets called each the working directory updates or a command is entered in a terminal, `gitmux` prints a tmux format string of git status, that gets shown in tmux status bar.
Or, nothing gets printed in case the working directory is not managed by Git.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @Jasha, the status line does not update when you change branches. However, Tmux has a window option called [`pane-border-status`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#configuring-the-pane-border). Combining @Nathan Kot's answer with this option results in the following configuration.

```
set -g pane-border-status bottom
set -g pane-border-format ' #(git -C #{pane_current_path} rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) #[fg=cyan]#{pane_current_path} '
```

This produces a pane border at the bottom (or top) that looks like this:

```
── master /path/to/your/repository ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Of course you can add colors and all other types of styling to it as you see fit.